# How do transceivers interact with the Ether bus in classic Ethernet?

Tags: ethernet, transceiver

I am reading *Computer Networks* 5th Edition [Tanenbaum/Wetherall] and there is the following diagram section 3.1 about classic Ethernet.

[image]

I am a bit confused on how to interpret the physical connection of the transceiver and the Ether cable, because it looks fairly intentional that the transceiver is itself connected to the Ether as if it were tapping into it.

Realistically, should there be another piece of hardware at each of the junctions between the transceiver and the Ether (creating a 3-way junction, 2 for the Ether on either side and 1 toward the transceiver)?

If so, what would that be called?

Comment: Perhaps a vampire tap? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vampire_tap

Comment: It is really tapping to it.

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea such hardware existed

Comment: What do you mean when you say "Ether" @shafe

Comment: the Ether is the shared medium in classic broadcast-based Ethernet.  In the diagram, it is depicted as the one long cord which all the devices are tapping into @Andyaka

Comment: There were two types of such Ethernet with different hardware – vampire taps for the older "thicknet", and (I believe) regular BNC T-connectors for thinnet.